# Regarding to printf in C

Tags: c

I have these two pieces of code:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("\nab");
    printf("\bsi");
    printf("\rha");
    return 0;
}
```

For the first one the output is `hai`. However if I write it this way instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("\nab");
    printf("\bsi");
    printf("\rsha");
}
```

The output that results is just `sha`. What's going on here? (Also I'm using `gcc`)

Comment: @zakinster Exact copy-paste of the above one!

Comment: If you understand the first case, you'll understand the second one. See the answers in the other post.

Comment: Why not just close it?

Answer (score 1):

**1)**

```
 printf("\nab");
```

it displays `ab`

```
printf("\bsi");
```

`\b`delete the last character (`\b` = backspace). Then you append  `si`

it displays `asi`

```
printf("\rha");
```

`\r` return to the beginning of the line (\r = carriage return). Then you print `ha` . hence you erase the first 2 characters of `asi`

Hence, it displays `hai`

**2)**

Same explanation for the first 2 steps.

On the third step, you return to the beginning of the line with `\r` and print 3 characters, erasing the 3 characters that were previsouly present.

Answer (score 0):

short explanation:

```
\n = moves to next line
\b = backspace - deletes 1 char
\r = moves cursor to 1st column of the line
```

so you get

```
ab
asi //for \bsi
hai // for \rha
```